# Wildcard searching using CONTAINS in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I've inherited an application that provides a search screen where users can enter criteria.  The stored procedure behind the scenes uses CONTAINS to perform the search.

My users want to have the ability to perform wildcard searches which are no problem since CONTAINS supports that.  However, the behavior is not what most would expect.  From MSDN...

> When  is a phrase, each word contained in the phrase is
>   considered to be a separate prefix. Therefore, a query specifying a
>   prefix term of "local wine*" matches any rows with the text of "local
>   winery", "locally wined and dined", and so on.

But let's say I actually did want to find the word "local" followed by any word beginning with "win" - surely there is a syntax for this?

I know I could recognize this scenario and fall back to a "LIKE" condition but performance would suffer and I can't help but think there is a way around this with CONTAINS.

Comment: Mr Most is wrong. CONTAINS, FREETEXT etc are used for full-text searching, just like Google. They aren't wildcard or regular expression searches.

Comment: Besides, you cut out the most important part of the documentation `When <prefix_term> is a phrase, each word contained in the phrase is considered to be a separate prefix.` When *the term* is a **phrase**. It's a *phrase* not a wildcard search

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql

Comment: As for what the customer wants, you should clarify this. `CONTAINS` etc are far more powerful than a wildcard search. It's also supported by full-text-search indexes, making it fast. **Why** do they want to revert to wildcards? Do they realize that they can't use any indexes in this case? Are they trying to shoehorn wildcard searches into the existing FTS code? Not a great idea